# In HTML path what's the different between ./ and /

Tags: html

What's the difference between `./` and `/` when entering the path to a file or folder in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` means the root of the current drive;

`./` means the current directory;

`../` means the parent of the current directory.

Comment: Don't mention it buddy. :)